# Editing a txt file with PHP/html

Tags: php, html

I'm currently using this PHP script to write to a text file, then another to read from that text file, however if I add more than one of these (while changing the name of textfile.txt to write to multiple text files, it updated both files with whatever is updated in the one field. How would I be able to allow this to two write to multiple text files without copy and pasting them to separate pages.

THE PHP used to edit/update:

```
<? 
if($_POST['Submit']){ 
$open = fopen("textfile.txt","w+"); 
$text = $_POST['update']; 
fwrite($open, $text); 
fclose($open); 
echo "File updated.<br />";  
echo "File:<br />"; 
$file = file("textfile.txt"); 
foreach($file as $text) { 
echo $text."<br />"; 
} 
}else{ 
$file = file("textfile.txt"); 
echo "<form action=\"".$PHP_SELF."\" method=\"post\">"; 
echo "<textarea Name=\"update\" cols=\"50\" rows=\"10\">"; 
foreach($file as $text) { 
echo $text; 
}  
echo "</textarea>"; 
echo "<input name=\"Submit\" type=\"submit\" value=\"Update\" />\n 
</form>"; 
} 
?>
```

I realize I didn't post my nonworking example, here it is:

```
<h2>content1</h2>
<? 
if($_POST['Submit']){ 
$open = fopen("../content.txt","w+"); 
$text = $_POST['update']; 
fwrite($open, $text); 
fclose($open); 
echo "File updated.<br />";  
echo "File:<br />"; 
$file = file("../content.txt"); 
foreach($file as $text) { 
echo $text."<br />"; 
} 
}else{ 
$file = file("../content.txt"); 
echo "<form action=\"".$PHP_SELF."\" method=\"post\">"; 
echo "<textarea Name=\"update\" cols=\"50\" rows=\"10\">"; 
foreach($file as $text) { 
echo $text; 
}  
echo "</textarea>"; 
echo "<input name=\"Submit\" type=\"submit\" value=\"Update\" />\n 
</form>"; 
} 
?> 
<br />
<h2>content2</h2>
<? 
if($_POST['Submit']){ 
$open = fopen("../content2.txt","w+"); 
$text = $_POST['update']; 
fwrite($open, $text); 
fclose($open); 
echo "File updated.<br />";  
echo "File:<br />"; 
$file = file("../content2.txt"); 
foreach($file as $text) { 
echo $text."<br />"; 
} 
}else{ 
$file = file("../content2.txt"); 
echo "<form action=\"".$PHP_SELF."\" method=\"post\">"; 
echo "<textarea Name=\"update\" cols=\"50\" rows=\"10\">"; 
foreach($file as $text) { 
echo $text; 
}  
echo "</textarea>"; 
echo "<input name=\"Submit\" type=\"submit\" value=\"Update\" />\n 
</form>"; 
} 
?>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OK I solved my own problem, it was a silly issue, I forgot to give unique names to the fields:

```
<h2>content1</h2>
<? 
if($_POST['Submit']){ 
$open = fopen("../content.txt","w+"); 
$text = $_POST['update']; 
fwrite($open, $text); 
fclose($open); 
echo "File updated.<br />";  
echo "File:<br />"; 
$file = file("../content.txt"); 
foreach($file as $text) { 
echo $text."<br />"; 
} 
}else{ 
$file = file("../content.txt"); 
echo "<form action=\"".$PHP_SELF."\" method=\"post\">"; 
echo "<textarea Name=\"update\" cols=\"50\" rows=\"10\">"; 
foreach($file as $text) { 
echo $text; 
}  
echo "</textarea>"; 
echo "<input name=\"Submit\" type=\"submit\" value=\"Update\" />\n 
</form>"; 
} 
?> 
<br />
<h2>content2</h2>
<? 
if($_POST['Submit2']){ 
$open = fopen("../content2.txt","w+"); 
$text = $_POST['update2']; 
fwrite($open, $text); 
fclose($open); 
echo "File updated.<br />";  
echo "File:<br />"; 
$file = file("../content2.txt"); 
foreach($file as $text) { 
echo $text."<br />"; 
} 
}else{ 
$file = file("../content2.txt"); 
echo "<form action=\"".$PHP_SELF."\" method=\"post\">"; 
echo "<textarea Name=\"update2\" cols=\"50\" rows=\"10\">"; 
foreach($file as $text) { 
echo $text; 
}  
echo "</textarea>"; 
echo "<input name=\"Submit2\" type=\"submit\" value=\"Update\" />\n 
</form>"; 
} 
?>
```